# Is the input field for writing a cover letter in Markdown? If not, why not?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

When writing a cover letter I get this screen:

[image: The cover letter screen]

Is this in Markdown? It doesn't look like it, since I just get **Bold text** and not **Bold text** when I click the "bold" button, and the editor is different, but it's difficult to be sure; especially since the Stack Exchange platform (including careers) uses Markdown pretty much *everywhere*, I would find it rather surprising and confusing if this *wouldn't* be in Markdown...

This doesn't just matter for bold text, but also for other formatting rules; will a single newline be a literal newline, or is it ignored (as in markdown?) Or do I need a blank line (two newlines) to introduce a new paragraph? Will two spaces at the end of a line introduce a line break? Can I use `code`? etc.

Comment: Just wondering that you mail address is not worth to been protected.

Comment: @rekire It's on my profile... I have a spam filter and would like people to get in touch if they feel like it ;-) Actually, I'm not sure why I hid my name, since you can find that on my website :-/ Ah well...

Comment: How did you write that  ***Bold Text*** example in this question without getting it bolded? In this comment I put an extra asterisk just to ask how, but why isn't the `Bold text` example you wrote bolded, because you put `**` around it...

Comment: @RuchirBaronia: You can write `\*\*Bold text\*\*` to get literal asterisks. (And incidentally, you can use the 'edit' link to see how someone did something in a question or answer.)

Comment: @ruakh Okay, thanks. For me, the edit link is faded out, and unclickable though. (I tried it in the beginning)

Comment: @RuchirBaronia Even without edit privileges, you can see the [revisions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/319459/revisions), and there you will find [source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/2ea1bcf7-fc97-4637-99fd-c9b2d8c81f17/view-source) links.

Comment: If that cover letter is meant to be sent by email, maybe they only allow minimal formatting since stuff like headings, syntax highlighting, images, etc. won't always be rendered properly in all email clients.

Comment: @this.lau_ Actually, Markdown works really well here, since you can just send the original Markdown source as the text/plain version (mails from Stack Overflow do this).

Comment: @Oriol How do I get to those revisions from the question?

Comment: If the post has been edited it's easy, there is a direct link. Otherwise you only need the post ID, you can see it in the URL of the page. Then the link is `http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/<postID>/revisions`.